# Vue3 click reloading whole page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

this my code in Vue3. Backend is in Django.

```
<template>
      <section>
        <div class="container py-5">
          <div class="row">
              <div v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-8 
                col-xl-6 text-center mx-auto ">
                <p class="fw-bold text-success mb-2">{{ item.name }}</p>
                <h3 class="fw-bold">{{ item.age }}</h3>{{ item.vote }}
                <form @submit.prevent="">
                <button class="btn" type="button" @click="onClickButtonYes(item.id)">
                  +</button>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      </section>
    </template>
    
  
  <script>
```

...

```
        async onClickButtonYes(id) {
          const fd = new FormData();
          fd.append("id", id);
          fd.append("isvoted", true);
          axios
            .put(`/api/v1/voteitem/${id}/`, fd)
            .then(response => {
              this.latest = response.data
              this.getlatestitems()
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.console.log(error);
            })
        },
        
      }
    }
    </script>
```

After click button whole page is reloading, why?
I tired add  @submit.prevent="", and also add type=button...
Where is problem? I asked chatgpt.. he say something about reactive.

Comment: What happens if you write `<form @submit.prevent="onClickButtonYes(item.id)">` and `<button type="submit">` ?

Comment: issue was in backend. I retutned none instead list

Answer (score 1):

The problem is outside the code you have posted.

Here is working playground with your code.

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    const list = ref([{ id: 1, name: "One", age: 100 }]);
    const onClickButtonYes = (id) => {
      console.log(id)
       const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("id", id);
        fd.append("isvoted", true);
        axios
          .put(`https://nowhere.com/api/v1/voteitem/${id}/`, fd)
          .then(response => {
            this.latest = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
          })
    }
    return {
      list, onClickButtonYes
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<section>
    <div class="container py-5">
      <div class="row">
          <div v-for="item in list" v-bind:key="item.id" class="col-md-8 
            col-xl-6 text-center mx-auto ">
            <p class="fw-bold text-success mb-2">{{ item.name }}</p>
            <h3 class="fw-bold">{{ item.age }}</h3>{{ item.vote }}
            <form>
               <button class="btn" type="button" @click="onClickButtonYes(item.id)">+</button>
            </form>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```